# Using GIT commands in a Perl Script on Windows

Tags: windows, git, perl

I'm still fairly new to GIT and how it works but I know it is possible to execute git commands in a windows command prompt. I've been able to set up a remote git repo on a linux machine and successfully push to it.

What I'm trying to do now is create a perl script to do exactly the same thing however when I run it, it comes back with:

*'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.*

I've got the PATH environment variable set up correctly (since I can run git commands outside of the script just fine) so not sure why it's coming back with that error.

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I have not used it mysqlf, but I did just install the Git CPAN module on my Win7 box and I wonder if that would be a better route than making the system calls you're currently doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the full path, eg

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git.exe" -ci .`
```

If you want to diagnose the problem, print out the ENV information using the following script and review the PATH being used by perl;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

foreach $key (keys(%ENV)) {
    printf("%-10.10s: $ENV{$key}\n", $key);
}
```

Comment: Specifying the full path worked for me, a bit annoying but it's okay since it's going to be in a script.